# How to style the current page indicator dot of UIPageControl differently?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This seems to be a very simple UI design requirement that I can't seem to find a way to implement easily in iOS. Basically the UI guys want the dot of the current page indicator to be an elongated dot instead of the regular dot. For example the standard dots of the UIPageControl are 14x14 on a Retina screen, while they want the dot of the current page to be 30x14, and I googled around but can't seem to find an easy way to accomplish this?

I've seen previous answers on how to put some custom UIImageViews into the subviews of the UIPageControl, however they don't seem to be working for the latest iOS versions. Simply changing the width of the dot for the current page indicator just messes up the spacing between the dots. I guess I can create my own custom UIView from the ground up for this feature, but that seems to be a lot of work for such a simple requirement.

So any idea how to make the current page indicator dot of UIPageControl to look differently from the rest of the dots? Thanks.

Comment: As a general rule, it's not a good idea to try to *directly modify* internals for many UI elements... you may be better off writing your own page control. Have you tried searching (google, or your favorite search engine) for `custom uipagecontrol`? Lots of results.

Comment: well, like I said, I'm sure I can write a custom UIView object from the ground up to accomplish the task, but it just seems to be quite an overkill for such a simple requirement. I googled Custom UIPageControl for sure, the top results are those 
SO answers about putting UIImageView into its subview, which I think no longer works. Also I'd think it'd be worth the effort to write my own UIView if I want to put image icons etc. to replace the dots, but to write a custom UIView just for an elongated dot? Is that really the only way?

Comment: You want only the "current" dot to be wider? And keep the spacing? So the dots will shift with each change? Or, do you want more spacing between the dots so their horizontal centers remain constant?

Comment: @DonMag, both can do, whichever is easier to achieve.

Comment: Well, I took a look at an older method of setting transforms on the dots, but it doesn't look like that still works with current iOS versions. It seems like creating a custom page control - *for a specific targeted use* - would be fairly trivial though. Building one that fully replicates a `UIPageControl` with customizable dots would take a little more work.

Answer (score 0):

I get it by rewriting UIPageControl.layoutSubviews.

my code: https://github.com/SumiaFish/KVPageContrl

[image]